# What will be the best practice which I should use?

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am newbie in Symfony2.
I have table in which exists 5 columns: answer_a, answer_b, answer_c, answer_d and correct_answer.

Answers a-d contain text answer in ABCD quiz. In correct_answer I have "a", "b", "c" or "d" string. How I can in the best possible way show user correct text answers? I should add to entity new "text_correctanswer" field? Or I should create in controller new array with correct text answers?

Comment: I would not create one column per answer, but just have a "one to many" relation between question and answer. The correct_answer then contains the ID of the correct answer. In Twig, you then only have to compare IDs to find out which answer was correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `oneToMany` relationships

> [Documentation with examples](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional)

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/** @Entity */
class Quiz {
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Answer", mappedBy="quiz")
     */
    protected $answers;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->answers = new ArrayCollection;
    }
}

/** @Entity */
class Answer {
    protected $id;
    protected $isCorrect;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Quiz", inversedBy="answers")
     * @JoinColumn(name="quiz_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $quiz;
}
```